# playing with View Layers - are they always all rendered?

Tags: rendering, performance, render-layers, viewlayers

I'm playing with View Layers since I have to separate a lot of stuff from a scene.
It's working great but I was wondering how it does impact the render performances.

If I have, let's say, 10 View Layers; but only one is used in the compositor.  Are they all rendered or just the one that is used ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, one by one. Each view layer has a "Use for Rendering" property -> *View Layer Properties (image stack icon) > View Layer > Use for Rendering*. Disable that if you want to exclude one view layer from the actual rendering.